# How to use Unicode characters from Decimal X to Decimal Y using charCodeAt() and fromCharCode()

Tags: javascript, unicode

I want to use Unicode characters from decimal X to decimal Y using charCodeAt() and fromCharCode()
I must write a JavaScript program to replace each character in a given string with the next in the English alphabet.
[UNICODE table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lirZn.png)

I write a program that is working well, but I don't understand how to choose symbols from Decimal 97 to Decimal 123
Here is my code

```
function stringEncoder(str) {
    let unicodeChars = str.split("");
    for (let i = 0; i < unicodeChars.length; i++) {
        let neededChars = unicodeChars[i].charCodeAt() - 97;//OR "a".charCodeAt()
        neededChars += 1;
        unicodeChars[i] = String.fromCharCode(neededChars + 97);//OR (neededChars + "a".charCodeAt())
    }
    return unicodeChars.join("");
}
console.log(stringEncoder("Abz"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple

```js
   const str = "Abz";
   for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { 
   const code = str[i].codePointAt(0); 
   if(code >=97 && code <=123){
   console.log("0x"+code); //replace char
   }
   else{
   console.log(str[i])
   }
   }
```

`log output`

> > A
> > 0x98
> > 0x122

Comment: But I need to replace the character with the next in Eng alphabit

Comment: Your output is not what I want )

Comment: @DanielHakobyan SO is not a free script writing service. Just apply `if(code >=97 && code <=123) {unicodeChars[i] = String.fromCharCode(code + 1);}` (a crucial point from the answer) to *choose symbols from Decimal 97 to Decimal 123*…

Answer (score 0):

"...next in the English alphabet"  You don't say what you want to happen to "Z" or "z".

This may help (just ascii, not unicode):

```
console.log('ABCDEFXYZabcdefxyz',nextChar('ABCDEFXYZabcdefxyz'));
function nextChar(str) {
  let ascii, ret = '';
  for (let i=0; i<str.length; i+=1) {
    ascii = str.charCodeAt(i)+1; // the codepoint+1
    if (ascii==91) ascii=65; // Z becomes A
    if (ascii==123) ascii=97; // z becomes a
    ret += String.fromCharCode(ascii); // build up output
  }
  return ret;
}
```